# alert(__dirname) not producing any output in an electron app

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I do not get the desired output when running the following electron app i.e alert box containing pwd as output. However, the commented line inside index.html seems to work fine. The developer console of the chromium window says "Uncaught ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>". This snippet is taken verbatim(except the commented line) from the book "Electron in action" by Steve Kinney 2019 edition.

any suggestions?

package.json is as follows

```
{
  "name": "bookmarker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "electron app",
  "main": "./app/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Wasim Aftab",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^9.0.0"
  }
}
```

main.js is as follows

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
let mainWindow = null;
app.on ('ready', () => {
    console.log('Hello, from electron');
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();
    mainWindow.webContents.loadFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

index.html is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
default-src 'self';
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
connect-src *">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bookmarker</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello from Electron</h1>
    <p>
        <button class="alert">Current Directory</button>
    </p>
</body>
<script>
    const button = document.querySelector('.alert');
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        alert(__dirname);
        // alert(window.location.pathname.replace(/[^\\\/]*$/, ''));
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with `alert(__dirname);`? also __dirname wont be what your expecting once packaged, instead use `app.getAppPath`, or `app.getPath` https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appgetapppath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__dirname` is a nodejs concept, it does not exist in the browser.

One way to resolve the issue is to set `nodeIntegration` to `true`:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    }
});
```

Another way would be to use a preload script (nodeIntegration is always enabled for preload scripts):

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        preload: (__dirname + "/preload.js")
    }
});
```

And then in the `preload.js` file:

```
window.__dirname = __dirname
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I am a newcomer in this field and the book I am using seems to have this kind of bug, can you suggest me a better book/resources to learn electron app development?

Comment: I'm not a book reader but the [official electron guide](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/README) looks helpful.

Comment: @WasimAftab If you're satisfied with the answer, please upvote and accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For electron v16.0.4, addition of `contextIsolation: false` also required

```
$ npx electron --version
v16.0.4
```

```
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      // enableRemoteModule: true,
    },
  });
```